# Font Awesome Icon in Next JS works with single Component/Variation only

Tags: reactjs, next.js, font-awesome

I've gotten the icons to import by using the import statements and then utilizing the imported components, however, many of the icons act like classes and if you want variations of the icon you need to add to the class. I cannot do this with pre-defined components and when I define icon = "" in quotes rather than importing a component it does not work.

When I go on the website, for example, it gives me this code for React:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-bold" />
```

My code:

```
import { faSolid, faBold } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

...

//Works
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBold} />

//Doesn't work
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-bold" />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={{faBold, faSolid}} />
```

I should also mention that I followed a small tutorial on from a blog and added this code to my pages/_app.js file:

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
config.autoAddCss = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you import the packages. It's recommended for newer users to do what was working:

```
import { faSolid, faBold } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

...

//Works
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBold} />

//faSolid doesnt exist.
```

If you **REALLY** want to do it the other way, and just so you know there are a lot of drawback to it, you would need to import the package [globally](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons#add-icons-globally) to your website. Again, I wouldn't recommend it, if you are just learning the package. It's extremelly easy to do individual imports, if you know the name of the icon you want to import then you type

```
import {faThumbsUp} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
```

the trick is when you go to fontawesome you pick your icon then in the upper left hand corner you can pick from which library theres solid, thin, etc. and that is the name of the package.

```
// regular
@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons

// solid
@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

They are all saved the same

```
faThumbsUp 
faAlien
faThumbtack
// etc...
```